# Angular 15 - Map (key/value) definition

Tags: angular, typescript

Back then I could write a simple `Map<string, number>` using `TypeScript` in `Angular2`. However, it seems the world spins too fast and now in `Angular15` the class `Map` does not even exists.

How do I get a simple statement like this:

```
counter: Map<string, number>;
```

to work on `Angular 15`?

Comment: Map isn't going anyware, what error do you have  ?

Comment: You can use Record<string,number> unless you neeed map features.

Comment: It seems like it was an IDE malfunction that didn't recognize the `Map`, I will confirm in few moments after compilation.